# mongoDB multiple counts query

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure of my documents in my MongoDB:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("59b799e462f0b9402dbcd69e"), "project": "ABC", "locked": true }

{ "_id": ObjectId("59b799e462f0b9402dbcd69f"), "project": "DEF", "locked": false }

{ "_id": ObjectId("59b799e462f0b9402dbcd70a"), "project": "XYZ", "locked": true }

{ "_id": ObjectId("59b799e462f0b9402dbcd70b"), "project": "ABC", "locked": true }

{ "_id": ObjectId("59b799e462f0b9402dbcd70c"), "project": "XYZ", "locked": false }
```

I want to find out the number of locked and unlocked projects grouped by the project field which should give me something like this:

```
[
  {
     project: "ABC",
     lockedCount: 2,
     unlockedCount: 0,
     totalCount: 2
  },
  {
     project: "DEF",
     lockedCount: 0,
     unlockedCount: 1,
     totalCount: 1
  },
  {
     project: "XYZ",
     lockedCount: 1,
     unlockedCount: 1,
     totalCount: 2
  }
]
```

Is it possible using just 1 query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) operation.

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate(
[{
    $group : {
        _id : "$project",
        "lockedCount" : {$sum : {
             $cond: { if: "$locked", then: 1, else: 0 }
           }},
           "unlockedCount" : {$sum : {
             $cond: { if: "$locked", then: 0, else: 1 }
           }},
         "totalCount" : {$sum : 1}
        }
    }]
)
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "XYZ",
    "lockedCount" : 1.0,
    "unlockedCount" : 1.0,
    "totalCount" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "DEF",
    "lockedCount" : 0.0,
    "unlockedCount" : 1.0,
    "totalCount" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "ABC",
    "lockedCount" : 2.0,
    "unlockedCount" : 0.0,
    "totalCount" : 2.0
}
```

### Updated

If you want to rename `_id` with `project`, then you can do that using `$project` at the end of `$group` operation, as

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate(
    [{
        $group : {
            _id : "$project",
            "lockedCount" : {$sum : {
                 $cond: { if: "$locked", then: 1, else: 0 }
               }},
               "unlockedCount" : {$sum : {
                 $cond: { if: "$locked", then: 0, else: 1 }
               }},
             "totalCount" : {$sum : 1}
            }
        },
        {
        $project : {
            _id : 0,
            project : "$_id",
            lockedCount : "$lockedCount",
            unLockedCount : "$unlockedCount",
            totalCount : "$totalCount"
            }
        }]
    )
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "project" : "XYZ",
    "lockedCount" : 1.0,
    "unLockedCount" : 1.0,
    "totalCount" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "project" : "DEF",
    "lockedCount" : 0.0,
    "unLockedCount" : 1.0,
    "totalCount" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "project" : "ABC",
    "lockedCount" : 2.0,
    "unLockedCount" : 0.0,
    "totalCount" : 2.0
}
```